# Ho to Extract DistilBERT Embeddings from a list containg 5000 records..?

Tags: list, extract, tokenize, embedding, distilbert

After tokenizing the dataset then we try to extract DistiBert Embeddings on our dataset(contains 5000 text records in dataframe) memory error occurred for the following code:

```
outputs = model(**tokenized_inputs0)
bert_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

So, we divide the dataframe into list using following code :

```
list_train = [final_Data1[i:i+100] for i in range(0,final_Data1.shape[0],100)]
```

**Now how to extract the DistilBERT Embeddings on the above list_train...????**

How to apply following code for extracting DistilBERT Embeddings on the list...?

outputs = model(**tokenized_inputs0)
bert_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to iterate over the list of data you created. You will have to do something with your predictions to get them out of memory, like saving them to a file, otherwise you'll still run out of memory.

```
batch_list = [final_Data1[i:i+100] for i in range(0,final_Data1.shape[0],100)] 

for batch in batch_list:

    outputs = model(**batch)
    bert_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state

    # do something with your outputs
```

Comment: As you passed parameter **batch to model, but model takes tokenized inputs as parameter. And I wants to know to store those embeddings..?